# Z3 benchmark Windows vs Linux

Tags: performance, benchmarking, z3

Is there any trustful benchmark regarding the Z3 performance in Linux vs Windows?

I know that Z3 is a Microsoft product but it is open source and Linux compatible.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Linux is well supported. The performance of Z3 on Linux is comparable with that of Windows.

Comment: I'm not aware of any public comparison.  My statement was based on my personal experience.
You should run your own benchmarks (or standard smtlib benchmarks) and assess yourself for the benchmarks you care about.